# Ubuntu hvm instance-storage backed instances?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I assume this has to be possible, but I am going crazy attempting to find it.

I'd like to create instance-storage backed i2.xlarge instances.  That instance type requires HVM, but the only HVM Ubuntu 12.04 AMIs I can find are EBS-backed.  Am I looking in the wrong place, or fundamentally misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at Ubuntu's cloud-images site (http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/trusty/current/) you should be able to find HVM instances for all regions.